# Codeigniter Complex MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I got two table which I would like to query from, which the users table and the user_job table

[users table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA0RK.png)

[user_job table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whXUe.png)

What I want to achieve is to write a MySQL query in CodeIgniter to display user information from users table if user_status in users table is "Active" And if there is no row in user_job table where user_job_status is equal to "On Probation" or user_job_status is equal to "Active"

In simple English, I want to display a user information if a user not currently on a job.

My current Codeigniter Model code is:

```
//get all user that are not currently assigned to a position
function get_idle_user(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('user_job', 'user_job.user_id_fk = users.user_id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->where('users.user_status','Active');
    $this->db->where("(user_job.user_job_status != 'Active' OR user_job.user_job_status != 'On Probation')", NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->group_by('users.user_id');
    if($query = $this->db->get()){
        return $query;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem with this code that it will still display user information if there is a row related to a user and user_job_status does not satisfy the where condition above.

Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->db->or_where("(user_job.user_job_status != 'Active' OR user_job.user_job_status != 'On Probation')", NULL, FALSE);`

Comment: please read: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ it always helps me to set up the right "tactic" for JOINs

Comment: I tried it but still giving me the same result. as the previous query. The first condition is the user should be active i.e user_status = "Active" The second condition is user should not hold a job i.e user_job_status should not be "Active" or "On Probation". I think the problem here is with the join statement. For example if I am an active user and I hold a job, but I also have previous job records in the database and the status is not "Active" or "On Probation" It will still display my info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after ...

```
$db->select('user_id_fk,COUNT(*) as `Tally`');
$db->where('user_job_status','On Probabtion');
$db->or_where('user_job_status','Active');
$db->group_by('user_id_fk');
$sub = $db->get_compiled_select('user_job_table');

$db->join("($sub) ujt",'ujt.user_id_fk = users.user_id AND Tally = 0','left');
$db->where('user_status','Active');

// View this query in full
//echo $db->get_compiled_select('users_table');

// Get the data
$data = $db->get('users_table')->result_array();
```

Note:

1. You don't need select('*') - it isn't needed
2. You don't need ->from() - it can be used in the get() element

I have left in the `get_compiled_select` which will allow you to see the full query and get an idea what its doing. You should comment out the $data line if you uncomment the echo line.

What this query is doing is saying get all users from the job_table which don't have the status Active or On Probation and a list of User ID's. That way you can then get Active users from the users_table and users with a tally of 0.